# Connect API.AI to Compute Engine Instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, dialogflow-es

I have an API.AI agent set up in my GCP project and I have a Compute Engine instance running a node server to be used as a webhook.  This instance does not have a public-facing URL but it does have a fixed instance name and an internal IP address.

When communicating between Compute Engine instances, you can use the instance name or the internal IP address, is there a way to get this working with API.AI?  I have tried using the internal IP address and the instance name (and the FQDN, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/internal-dns)) but I just get one of the following errors:

Using Internal IP: `Webhook call failed. Error: Request timeout.`

Using Instance Name or FQDN: `Webhook call failed. Error: Webhook response was empty.`

How can I get an API.AI agent to communicate with a Compute Engine instance?  They live in the same GCP project so they should be able to talk to each other...

Important note:  we do not want to use the external IP or create a public-facing URL for security concerns, especially if customers will be entering their data into the chat system.

Answer (score 1):

API.AI webhooks can't "talk to" internal GCP IPs or instance names, you'll need to [create an static IP for your Compute Engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) and either use that static IP in API.AI's webhook field or create [use GCP to create a external DNS name using the static IP](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-dns-configure#proc_gke_gce) and use that in API.AI webhook field.

Or if you'd prefer here is a Medium post walking through how to add a custom domain to your Compute Engine instance: https://medium.com/@kevin_moses_ang/adding-custom-domain-to-your-google-compute-engine-713fb3fae4e8

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense, but it also is where we have the real problem.  My organization is actually working to get rid of external IPs completely for security reasons.  We don't want any part of this to be public-facing, especially if it is where customer data is going to go

Comment: You can use API.AI's webhook authentication (HTTP basic auth, or customer HTTP headers): https://api.ai/docs/fulfillment#authentication but there currently isn't an option to use API.AI's webhook and not have a externally accessible IP address.